# BIOS Update: Do I need to install all versions one after another

Tags: bios

I just bought a new PC. 
Then I started to download a long list of update drivers etc.

When I opened the BISO update download page, I found that there are several BIOS versions to download.
Here is the [link](https://www.gigabyte.com/au/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios);

My question is:
Do I need to install all of them from the earliest to the latest version? Or I just need to install the latest version which includes every previous version?(It doesn't like so, because I saw the F5 version is around 9MB not larger than any previous versions.)

Comment: Just use caution: do *not* interrupt the update, since that could brick the PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install the newest version. Newest version has all the previous fixes, this is for Gigabyte boards, others like Dell And HP may be best to install each one working up to the newest.

Comment: I have not observed this to always be the case. Specifically, a few Dell Latitude models only seem to be able to jump 3 or so versions, or require one particular update before later updates work.

Comment: It is with Gigabyte, which is what the asker is referring to.

Comment: If there is a check, it will be in the software that patches the firmware, and likely will provide a message indicating the update cannot be performed and for what reason.

Comment: Not always, had many HP bios updates brick the laptop, turns out the engineers said you had to update the bios incrementally. which was not stated in the bios update notes.

Comment: Each BIOS-update is `cumulative` : ref: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/BIOS-Update/m-p/6452859/highlight/true#M150649

Comment: I cant tell you how many HP laptops have been bricked by installing the latest bios instead of installing each one. They can say anything they want but experience tells me otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Some versions require specific previous versions. Usually this is documented, but sometimes it is not.

But most BIOS updates are cumulative and contain all updated code from previous updates.

I will typically start with the most recent, check if it lists a specific required minimum version, and if it doesn't I just try installing it.

If it installs, great. You're done. If it doesn't install I go back a few versions and download and install that one.

Once one installs successfully I start back at the latest one again, repeating this process until the latest update installs.

Comment: IMHO, a waste of time.  ESPECIALLY with a modern system.

Comment: While I have seen this happen, it was long ago and rare. Typically, this was due to lazy programming where an update *patched* a BIOS, not *replace* it.

Comment: I currently deal with it on two different models of computers. One a 6 year old model, one only about 3 years old.

Comment: Still, following these steps will result in a successful BIOS patch whether your system has this odd problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

90% of the time, the answer is that you only need to install the latest version of the bios.

Occasionally, the hardware manufacturer drops support for certain devices or updates things like the mechanism used to update the bios. On these occasions there will typically be a not on the installation page detailing that you should not install that version of the bios unless you have already installed a specific version first.

For example, taken from the Gigabyte page

> Update AGESA 1.0.0.2 for 3rd Gen AMD Ryzen™ CPU full support
> Note:
> U1. If you are using Q-Flash Utility to update BIOS, make sure you have updated BIOS to F31 before F40
> U2. Before update BIOS to F40, you have to install EC FW Update Tool (B19.0517.1 or later version) to avoid 4DIMM DDR incompatibility on 3rd Gen AMD Ryzen™ CPU
> U3. Due to BIOS ROM size limited, NO Bristol Ridge (AMD 7th Gen A-series/ Athlon™ X4 series) APU support.

If you cannot see anything similar, the just download the newest version.